# Submit angular form in unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-ng-form, karma-mocha, ng-submit

Is there a way to submit a form in unit test ?

I have a form like

```
<!-- notice that the controller is defined using controllerAs syntax -->
<form name="sign_up" ng-submit="auth.signUp(email, password)" role="form">
```

for example

```
SignUpCtrl = new _$controller_ 'SignUpCtrl', $scope: scope
SignUpForm = scope.sign_up # this holds the signup form

it '#signUp(email, password)', ->
  controllerSignUpMethod = sinon.spy SignUpCtrl, 'signUp'

  SignUpForm.email.$setViewValue 'em@il.com'
  SignUpForm.password.$setViewValue 'pa$$word'
  SignUpForm.confirm_password.$setViewValue 'pa$$word'
  # I can't find a way to submit the form here
  expect(controllerSignUpMethod).to.be.called
```

the `SignUpForm` is angular `fromController`.. but it I can't find a way to use it or the `scope` to submit the form...

One last thing... due some unfortunates I **cannot** use `protractor` or any other `e2e` package... my only option is to go with the unit tests... and the views (signup form) could be changed later... so there must exist a unit test for it to insure that it's still calling the correct controller with the correct parameters... the `SignUpForm` is loaded from templates in each test... so it's the actual form not just a mocked `$templateCache` of it

Comment: Okay I see now.  You can't just SignUpCtrl.signUp()?  or is it SignUpCtrl.auth.signUp()?

Comment: This is the view.. And it uses controller as syntax... So `auth.signUp` calls the `SignUpCtrl.SignUp` method... The views would be modified later by the designer... So we have to make sure that its still working after the modifications

Comment: So the `SignUpForm` loads the template and do some unit testing on validations of the model... Then it has to make sure that its calling the correct controller method (`SignUpCtrl.signUp(email, password)`)

Comment: Oh okay, I wouldn't know the answer to this, but I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675196/trigger-click-event-on-an-angularjs-directive-in-mocha-test-suite).  Maybe it could help?  It's testing a directive, but it's very similar.  Using [jqlite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)  `.triggerHandler('submit')`, but I'm not sure on what.  `SignUpForm.triggerHandler('submit')` maybe?  Best of luck.

Comment: That's awesome news, glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since the controller is defined using `controllerAs: 'auth'` syntax..

use the following code :

```
SignUpCtrl = new _$controller_ 'SignUpCtrl as auth', $scope: scope
SignUpForm = scope.sign_up

it '#signUp(email, password)', ->
  controllerSignUpMethod = sinon.spy SignUpCtrl, 'signUp'

  SignUpForm.email.$setViewValue 'em@i.l'
  SignUpForm.password.$setViewValue 'pa$$word'
  SignUpForm.confirm_password.$setViewValue 'pa$$word'

  #=> trigger the submit event on the anugular element (or the compiled form)
  #=> you can get this using element.find('form')
  #=> or save it as the output of $compile(form)(scope)
  FormElement.triggerHandler('submit')

  expect(spy).to.be.calledWith 'em@i.l', 'pa$$word'
```